# Prevent multiple unwanted fetch requests sent during re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I built a react-app using [react-hook-speech-to-text](https://github.com/Riley-Brown/react-speech-to-text). It converts speech to text and sends this text to a mongodb database via a backend node server. If a user says "hello world", then it will convert this to a string and store it in an array called **results**.
The I app built was supposed to send each string once to the database but it sends multiple fetch requests and fills up the database with unnecessary copies of the same string. Below is the code I have written in the App.js file. I want it to only send one fetch request per new string converted to text.

```
import React from 'react';
import useSpeechToText from 'react-hook-speech-to-text';

export default function App() {
  const {
    error,
    interimResult,
    isRecording,
    results,
    startSpeechToText,
    stopSpeechToText,
  } = useSpeechToText({
    continuous: true,
    useLegacyResults: false,
  });

  if (error) return <p>Web Speech API is not available in this browser ‍</p>;

  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center bg-indigo-400'>
      <div className='flex flex-col justify-center'>
        <h1 className='uppercase text-3xl bold text-white text-center'>
          Recording: {isRecording.toString()}
        </h1>
        <button
          className='bg-white text-indigo-400 px-4 py-2 rounded border-white border-2 transition hover:bg-indigo-400 hover:text-white'
          onClick={isRecording ? stopSpeechToText : startSpeechToText}
        >
          {isRecording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        </button>
        <ul>
          {results.map((result) => {
            try {
              fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/commands', {
                method: 'POST',

                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ command: result.transcript }),
              })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((myRes) => console.log(myRes));
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('Error posting data: ' + error);
            }
            return <li key={result.timestamp}>{result.transcript}</li>;
          })}
          {interimResult && <li>{interimResult}</li>}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `useEffect()` hook?

Comment: Yeah, i had tried it first but was unable to get it to work. Do you know a way to implement useEffect hook here?

Comment: I tried, and it seems like the `results` array is very voltaile and is constantly changing, which means the `useEffect` will constantly get triggered even if I specify `results` as a dependency. It might help to add a delay using debounce to the whole process of sending requests.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a separate component for one `result` item. There you can add a `useEffect` hook.

The dependency of the `useEffect` should basically *the thing that would make a re-fetch necessary if it changes*, i.e. probably your `result.transcript`.

That is easy if `result.transcript` is just a string, then you could just pass `transcript` to the component, put it into the dependencies and the fetch parameters.

The result of the fetch then needs to be passed back by some kind of callback instead of just returned.